# Firebase data modelling for live search/type-ahead

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data set of a local 10 mile running race over the past decade or so.

Each year looks like this:
http://www.nlaa.ca/results/rr/2018/20180722tely10results.php

For my version 0.1, I've combined all of these tables into a giant json object:

```
[
    {
        "year": "2005",
        "position": "1",
        "name": "Colin Fewer",
        "chip-time": "52:05",
        "gun-time": "52:04",
        "class": "M25-29",
        "class-place": "1/58"
    },
    {
        "year": "2005",
        "position": "2",
        "name": "Dean Aylward",
        "chip-time": "52:57",
        "gun-time": "52:55",
        "class": "M25-29",
        "class-place": "2/58"
    },
    {
        "year": "2005",
        "position": "3",
        "name": "Peter Power",
        "chip-time": "54:49",
        "gun-time": "54:48",
        "class": "M40-44",
        "class-place": "1/126"
    }
]
```

I'm just dumping this entire file onto the page at the moment and interacting with it directly. This works fine, but the json file is massive — requiring a 5.5mb download. So that's no good.

Instead, I want to try and move this data to Firebase. Trouble is, I don't know how to structure this data.

Should each year be a collection and each runner be a document?

Should the whole thing be completely flat?  IE: one collection and every entry is a new document? (basically how my json file is now)

Will this be efficient enough to perform type-ahead searches and show live results as you type?

The current dataset has about 45,000 entries (the race has about 4,000 people run it each year).

Appreciate any basic advice anyone has!

Here's my app so far for reference:
https://saltcod.github.io/mytely

Here's the structure I'm currently thinking:

[image]

Comment: I like this well structured, thoughtful question. The one item omitted was what kind of type-ahead searches are you performing? i.e. In the UI the user selects 'search names' and then starts to enter a runners name which then presents a list of matches? Or is there some other functionality? I think the answer will depend on what the expected behavior is from the UI.

Comment: Thank you @Jay!  The idea is to reproduce what's currently going on in the prototype: https://saltcod.github.io/mytely/   When I start typing my name, I'll see matches returned across all years.

I'm honestly curious if this is even "possible" with a firebase setup. Anything is possible I recognize, but wondering if querying a 40,000 item firebase store with every keyup is a good idea.

Comment: While technically the queries are 'easy', you're going to need to keep banging on Firebase with each keystroke. So it's not the quantity of data or even query'ing Firebase (it can easily handle 40k records), it's the lag between each keystroke for the user due to pushing the data over the internet. Even a slight delay will make the UI feel unnatural and sluggish and if you have an extra laggy location it will really feel noticeable. So, not I would not recommend that strategy.